# Void overlapping image to prevent mouse over event

Tags: css, reactjs, popover

I have a problem with an icon I'm overlapping over other image

Originally, the image I'm showing has a hover popover that displays information about that product, we're aggregating a new feature to mark the products for example as removed or forbidden, the problem is that when the image icon overlaps the product's then it takes the mouse over event causing that when the mouse is over it the popover doesn't display.

Adding a listener to the icon to trigger the popover would be problematic (a bit difficult and disrupts the continuity of the popover being displayed)

Is there css trick or other way in which the icon can be inhibited from taking events and letting the underlying image to throw the events, kind of making the icon "transparent" for events? (don't know if this is possible at all)

Thanks in advance!

[Sample overlapped images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTaQf.png)

Comment: It is **very** hard to help you without seeing your code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Nevermind @JonP `pointer-events: none;` did the trick, that css property makes objects transparent to events so underlying image is always triggering the hover, thanks a lot for your help!